Weighted Covariance by Weighted Centering Matrices
Lets say we have matrix with data $X \in R^{N \times d}$. $X$ can be centered using a centering matrix $H = I - \dfrac{1_N 1_N^\intercal}{N}$. As $H$ is symmetric and idempotent we can define the covariance: $
Cov(X) = \dfrac{1}{N} (HZ)^\intercal (HZ) = \frac{1}{N} Z^\intercal H^\intercal H Z = \frac{1}{N} Z^\intercal H Z.$
Now lets say $X$ is equipped with a weighting, i.e. a vector $\omega \in R^N$. How can we define the weighted covariance in terms of weighted centering matrices $H_\omega$?
My first attempt would be to use: $H_\omega = I - \frac{\omega 1_N}{\sum \omega_i}$.
But this choice of $H_\omega$ is not symmetric. Other choices have been:
$H_\omega = I - \frac{\omega \omega^\intercal}{||\omega||_2^2},$ which is both symmetric and idempotent, but its quadratic nature makes me nervous.
Question: How can we define the weighted covariance in terms of weighted centering matrices $H_\omega$?

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$. We write the covariance between two columns of two columns of $X$ as $Cov(X_{:,d_i},X_{:,d_j}) = \mathbb{E}[(X_{:,d_i} - \mathbb{E}\left[X_{:,d_i}])(X_{:,d_j} - \mathbb{E}[X_{:,d_j}])\right]$, where $\mathbb{E}$ is the regular expectation operator.
Given a vector of weights $\omega \in \mathbb{R^N}$, define another expectation operator $\mathbb{E}_\omega[X_{:,d}] = \frac{1}{\Omega} \sum_n w_n X_{n,d} = \hat{X}_{:,d}^\omega$, where $\Omega = \sum_n w_n$. The covariance induced by this operator is naturally:
$$
Cov_\omega (X_{:,d_i},X_{:,d_j}) = \frac{1}{\Omega} \sum_n w_n (X_{n,d_i} - \hat{X}_{:,d_i}^\omega)(X_{:,d_j} - \hat{X}_{:,d_j}^\omega)
$$
If we now consider the variance-covariance matrix $Cov_\omega (X)$ we can rewrite the above equation in matrix form as:
$$
Cov_\omega (X) = \frac{1}{\Omega} \left( X^\intercal \text{diag}(\omega)X - \frac{X^\intercal \omega \omega^\intercal X}{\Omega} \right) = \frac{1}{\Omega} X^\intercal \left( \text{diag}(\omega) - \frac{\omega \omega^\intercal}{\Omega} \right) X
$$
So $H_w = \text{diag}(\omega) - \frac{\omega \omega^\intercal}{\Omega}$ would be the natural centering matrix for the weighted covariance. We notice that $H_\omega$ is symmetric, but not idempotent. This makes sense - applying $H_w$ twice would be to weight the covariance twice.
